# CS50 Problem set 4 Recover not recovering images

Tags: c, cs50, recovery

I could do with some advice for this, to me this makes sense logically however when I run check50 only one of the images are recovered. I've looked through the code multiple times so I don't think its a syntax error so it must be some error with the logic. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <cs50.h>

typedef uint8_t BYTE;

bool is_jpeg_header(BYTE buffer[]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Check if command line argument is valid
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./recover image\n");
        return 1;
    }
    // Open memory card files
    char* mem_card = argv[1];
    FILE* inptr = fopen(mem_card, "r");
    if (inptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("File not found/n");
        return 1;
    }
    BYTE buffer[512];
    bool found_first_jpeg = false;
    int image_count = 0;
    char filename[8];
    FILE* outptr = NULL;

    while (!feof(inptr) && fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, inptr) == true)
    {
        // Check if we have found a JPEG
        if (is_jpeg_header(buffer) == true)
        {
            // Check if this is the first JPEG
            if (found_first_jpeg == false)
            {
                found_first_jpeg = true;
                sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", image_count);
                outptr = fopen(filename, "w");
                fwrite(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, outptr);
                image_count++;
            }
            // If this isn't the first JPEG, close file current JPEG and open new one for new JPEG
            else
            {
                fclose(outptr);
                image_count++;
                sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", image_count);
                outptr = fopen(filename, "w");
            }
        }
        // If we haven't found a new JPEG:
        else if (is_jpeg_header(buffer) == false)
        {
            // Continue reading file if we have not found first JPEG
            if (found_first_jpeg == false)
            {
                continue;
            }
            // Continue writing current JPEG into current file
            else
            {
                fwrite(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, outptr);
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(inptr);
    fclose(outptr);
    return 0;
}

bool is_jpeg_header(BYTE buffer[])
{
    if (((buffer[0] == 0xff) && (buffer [1] == 0xd8) && (buffer[2] == 0xff) && ((buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This is the error code I receive from check50

```
:) recover.c exists.
:) recover.c compiles.
:) handles lack of forensic image
:) recovers 000.jpg correctly
:( recovers middle images correctly
    001.jpg not found
:( recovers 049.jpg correctly
    recovered image does not match
```

Comment: The check results are very clear:*expected exit code 0, not 1*. You're not supposed to exit with an exit code of 1. Look at where you `return 1` from `main`, and figure out why such an early exit is triggered. Specifically, `fopen("argv[1]", "r")` tries to open a file named literally `argv[1]`. No such file will ever exist in the test system, I can assure you of that. This will never ever succeed. Notice that the "fix" is trivial :) It's a simple typo.

Comment: Ah thank you I figured it was something to so with the first two statements but completely overlooked that. Such a trivial mistake. I changed that and image 000.jpg is recovered but 001.jpg and 0.49.jpg aren't which I'm stumped by

Comment: Note that the `fread == true` comparison will work, but it's technically incorrect. You're looking for the number of items read. The number should be `1` - exactly what you gave in the 3rd argument to `fread`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One bug I see is that `filename` is too short: you haven't left any room for the terminating zero. That's undefined behavior, and likely your source of trouble.

But the logic overall is very convoluted for what amounts to a simple problem. Here's how I'd write it. Since you're not in general checking for errors, I've left it that way - it's likely OK for this test assignment, although I've not read it. It does help to return different error codes for different errors though - it'd have really helped with the original typo!

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef uint8_t bool;
static const bool true = 1;
static const bool false = 0;

bool is_jpeg_header(const uint8_t buffer[]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Check if command line argument is valid
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./recover image\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Open the memory card image
    char* mem_card = argv[1];
    FILE* infile = fopen(mem_card, "r");
    if (!infile)
    {
        printf("File not found/n");
        return 2;
    }

    uint8_t buffer[512];
    int image_count = 0;
    char filename[9];
    FILE* outfile = NULL;

    while (!feof(infile) && fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, infile) == 1)
    {
        // Check if we have found a JPEG
        if (is_jpeg_header(buffer))
        {
            // If we're already writing output - close it
            if (outfile)
                fclose(outfile);

            sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", image_count);
            outfile = fopen(filename, "w");
            image_count ++;
        }

        // Write the output if we're ready to write
        if (outfile)
            fwrite(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, outfile);
    }
    fclose(infile);
    fclose(outfile);
    return 0;
}

bool is_jpeg_header(const uint8_t buffer[])
{
    return
        buffer[0] == 0xff
        && buffer[1] == 0xd8
        && buffer[2] == 0xff
        && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0;
}
```

Comment: Ah I thought I had taken into account the null terminating character, another trivial mistake. Unfortunately even after changing the filename size to 9 elements I'm still encountering the same problem. I agree the logic is slightly overcomplicated, I tried using both my psuedocode I wrote and the psuedocode provided in the lecture which has likely made things convoluted

Comment: After running check50 on your code yours works and definitely seems a lot easier to follow. I'm still curious as to why mine hasn't worked though. I also can't use your code for my own answer due to the courses academic honesty policy

Comment: @Biggles-2 Have you actually used a debugger on your code? It should be easier to figure out what's wrong that way. The filename size change is absolutely required. There are other problems in addition to that of course, but I can't just give you the entire story about what's wrong, right? I can only show what works and you can then compare behavior between the two :) Also note that I have not tested my code at all: the reason it works is luck, but also because it's a really simple problem that shouldn't be overcomplicated. It's easy to get it right if you don't make it hard for yourself.

Comment: You've probably noticed that the `found_first_jpeg` condition you have is unnecessary: the output file pointer does this job already. Try getting rid of that condition maybe, it's just an extra layer of complication.

Comment: Also, style-wise: those `== true` and `== false` checks are just a big no. They are wrong. The job of `if` is to check whether the expression is true. Comparing it to true is not guaranteed to work in C at all. It'd only work in C++, but even there it's a stylistic snafu. In C there are no boolean expressions at all, and expressions can be true while being unequal to `true`. Because in C all you got is `true` being a numeric constant 1. There's nothing else going on.

Comment: Hi @Reinstate Monica, I went ahead to the next lecture and have just come back to this and used your advice and figured out where I went wrong. I've also amended the syntactic issues with regards to the if conditions, I had no idea they were such a big no but the code reads a lot better now without them. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

[why while(!foef() is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

regarding:

```
printf("File not found/n");
```

Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.

When the error indication comes from a C library function should also output to `stderr`, the text reason the system thinks the error occurred. The function: 
    perror( "your error msg" );

is made for this purpose.

regarding:

```
printf("Usage: ./recover image\n");
```

1) this should be to `stderr`, not `stdout`. 2) don't hardcode the executable name. Suggest:

```
fprintf( stderr, "Usage: %s imagefile\n". argv[0] );
```

regarding:

```
while (!feof(inptr) && fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, inptr) == true)
```

1) `true` and `false` are defined in `stdbool.h` so that header file needs to be included.

2) `fread()` returns the number of items read. (which is also the third parameter, (and remembering the prior statement about `while( !foef() )` so the statement would be much better written as:

```
while (  fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, inptr) == 1)
```

which catches EOF and partial reads and I/O errors.

regarding;

```
outptr = fopen(filename, "w");
```

The success/failure of the call to `fopen()` is not under the control of your program, Therefore, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

regarding:

```
if (is_jpeg_header(buffer) == false)         
{             // Continue reading file if we have not found first JPEG 
    if (found_first_jpeg == false)             
    {                 
        continue;             
    }             // Continue writing current JPEG into current file  

    else
```

This code can be completely removed

the posted code fails to close the current output file after the second file is started.

the posted code always reads `sizeof(buffer)` bytes (assuming no errors) but there is no guarantee that each image data is exactly a multiple of `sizeof(buffer)` in length so it can miss the encounter with the next image AND can result in part of the header, etc data from the next image being written into the current output file.

Please post the function:

```
is_jpeg_header(buffer)
```

as it is unlikely to correct the problems listed above.